# Strange UINavigationController issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently trying to use push segue to navigate between two views. This works fine elsewhere in my app, no problems. However, in this particular location, I'm presented with the following error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
 reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is
 managed by an instance of UINavigationController.
```

Now here's the thing, i know exactly what this error means, and exactly how to fix it.

Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller on the view controller i'm trying to push from.

The thing is, I've done that already and the error persists. Any ideas?

For what it's worth, the navigation bar doesn't even appear in the view that was embedded inside the nav controller.

Here is the current setup

I have a ViewController on the storyboard that is setup to inherit from UIViewController. That controller is embedded inside a UINavigation controller via the above method.

On this view controller view, there are two buttons. Inside IB I have dragged a push segue from each of those buttons to the respective view controllers I would like to present.

I've also tried doing the segue in code via the following:

```
- (IBAction)btnTerms:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *termsVC = [STORYBOARD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TermsOfServicesViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:termsVC animated:YES];
}
```

In the above case, nothing happens at all. No crashes or anything. Debugger breakpoints confirm that the method is being hit, though.

**Update as per Phillip's question**

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:termsVC animated:YES];
```

[image]

[image]

```
- (IBAction) btnSignUpCLicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self presentViewController:[STORYBOARD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignUpViewController"] animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: My guess is the at you are do this push from an instance of your controller that is not the instance you have in the storyboard. You need to provide more information about the structure of your app. What controllers do you have? How did you get to the controller that is causing this error?

Comment: @Mayur: I've now reviewed a few of your edits. It's good that you do it, but please do not replace "and" with "&", and both "I" and "I'm" are really written with capital "I".

Comment: @rdelmar That's an interesting theory. I'll update the question with more information

Comment: When you do `[self.navigationController pushViewController:termsVC animated:YES];`, is `self.navigationController` non-nil?

Comment: @PhillipMills Excellent question. The debugger does in fact show it as niil. I know it's embedded though, why would that happen?

Comment: Is the navigation controller in your picture marked as the initial view controller in the storyboard?  If not, what loads it and presents it?

Comment: @PhillipMills It's not the initial view controller. The presenting view controller is different. I'll post the presenting code. Strangely, I have another VC presented the same way, and it's also embedded inside it's own NavController, but it doesn't have any of these issues

Comment: I **suspect** you need to instantiate the navigation controller and present it.  The embed segue should look after loading your sign-up controller.  When you told it to "Embed In", that creates a relationship from container to contained but not necessarily the reverse.

Comment: @PhillipMills sorry, but I'm not sure I understand you. Are you saying there may be some extra steps in between just embedding the VC? What confuses me about that is that I don't recall having to do that before.

Comment: The quick test would be to remove the identifier @"SignUpViewController" from your sign-up controller and assign it to the navigation controller that embeds it and observe the result.

Comment: @PhillipMills That fixed it! Would you mind putting that in an answer so I can give you credit for it? I'll keep in mind that you need to present the nav controller first, then everything else follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

Embedding a view controller inside a navigation controller will cause the embedded controller to load when its navigation controller does.  The reverse is not implied (, which is reasonable because there might be a case where the embedded controller would be also useful standalone).

Comment: If I present the nav  controller instead of the vc it's embedding this all works great. Not sure why I didn't think of that before, but thanks so much for all the help. I'll keep this in mind for the future!